# Tomcat error - syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I am trying to run a local **Tomcat configuration**, but I'm getting the following error...

> Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: eval: line 369: syntax error near unexpected token `('

The error is cause by the following line :

> /Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: eval: line 369: `exec "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" "-**
>   Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/xxx.xxxxx/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.3/tomcat/Tomcat_8_5_32_(1)_verafin/conf/logging.properties"

I didn't include the rest of the `exec` command because it is obvious that the error is being caused by the following...

```
Tomcat_8_5_32_(1)_verafin/conf/logging.properties
```

What is very strange is that I am not even using `Tomcat 8`. The configuration I included is `Tomcat 7`, as shown below...

[image]

The error occurred after my `Intellij` restarted. When it booted up again, my `Tomcat` wouldn't run anymore and gives me the error above. Why won't it recognize the path to my `Tomcat 7` directory even though it seems that it does? And where might the `Tomcat 8` be coming from and how can I remove it?

Comment: For an immediate fix, you might want to remove the parentheses from the path.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not even sure where that path is coming from

Comment: May be you need to check TOMCAT_HOME for that defined server, should point to tomcat7 installation directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, what i did was pass the VM option as key/value inside the Startup/Connection, just like that:
[image]

That solved the problem for me.